# Throwing exceptions from JBPM WorkItemHandlers?

Tags: exception, jbpm

I'm a little confused about the subject of throwing exceptions from JBPM work item handlers and handling the exception elsewhere in the business process. We're using JBPM 6.0.3 to run in Jboss EAP 6.1.

The [JBPM User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMExceptionManagement.html) implies that you should never throw exceptions from within a WorkItemHandler. Instead, the handler should catch them and either handle them some way or else convert them to an error message, signal, or similar. JBPM even provides work item handler wrappers which catch signals and converts them to messages for you. There's no discussion in the user guide about handling exceptions any other way.

Then we have the jbpm-workitems package, which contains quite a few handlers that are specifically coded to throw exceptions. Anything in that package which inherits from [AbstractLogOrThrowWorkItemHandler](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-workitems/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/AbstractLogOrThrowWorkItemHandler.java) can throw a WorkItemHandlerRuntimeException, for example. Maybe these handlers are only supposed to be used by wrapping them, but that seems like an odd design choice.

I've also found [this third-party documentation page](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Custom+tasks#Customtasks-Modelinganerror) for something called Magnolia, which shows a different technique. You define an error message type where the error code value is the fully-qualified name of an exception class. Then you attach an error boundary event to the activity that calls the handler. If the handler throws that exception, it'll be caught by the error event. I've tested this method and it works fine; it even captures the exception object into a process variable.

I'm confused because the method shown on the Magnolia page is completely different from the method in the JBPM user guide, and there is nothing in the JBPM guide which even hints that the Magnolia method will work. The Magnolia method seems to be easier to use, but I'm concerned that it might not be supported.

What is the best-practice way to handle exceptions thrown by work item handlers? Is the Magnolia method something that's deprecated, or that works only by accident? Or is it something that I can count on continuing to work?

Edit: What prompted this question is that our team wanted to use the [`RESTWorkItemHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jbpm/jbpm-workitems/6.1.0.Final/org/jbpm/process/workitem/rest/RESTWorkItemHandler.java) from jbpm-workitems. This handler will throw exceptions in certain very ordinary circumstances. The JBPM documentation basically says not to let your work item handlers throw exceptions; catch them within the handler, or wrap the handler in a decorator that catches exceptions. That would make handlers like the REST handler finicky to construct and register properly. And I thought it strange that JBPM would maintain a bunch of standard work item handlers that couldn't be used without wrapping them in another handler.

Then I found the method described in the Magnolia documentation, which avoids having to wrap the handler in a decorator. But the method in the Magnolia documentation isn't described in the JBPM documentation.

Comment: Which version of jBPM are you using?

Comment: @jl987 Oops, added version info. We're using JBPM 6.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are asking two questions which we can address separately, and let's see if we can address your concerns:

1. What is the best-practice way to handle exceptions thrown by work item handlers?

There is no silver bullet here. It depends on many different factors such as:

- Can you recover from the exception? For example, if jBPM and the resource you access in the WorkItemHandler respect the same XA transaction and the exception in question marked the transaction for rollback, your options are limited as the persistent state won't be stored.
- If you can recover, what do you want to do? Retry, intervene manually, abort the process and log the failure, or reverse previous activities in a compensation flow?
- Based on what you want to do, where is the best place to do it? Java or BPMN? BPMN is good for compensation, but a WorkItemHandler or perhaps a Decorator may be better for retries. Maybe it is a combination of the two and you convert a Java Exception to a BPMN Signal/Error that indicates to the caller it should retry.

There is no single answer here and many different approaches could be valid.

2. Is the Magnolia method something that's deprecated, or that works
   only by accident? Or is it something that I can count on continuing
   to work?

Nope, not deprecated, and looking at the code I'd say it works by design. Just keep in mind that in their example you are using Magnolia's decorators, in which case you should ask the Magnolia guys whether they will support it in future. But there are many examples of decorators and you are free to write some yourself to implement the exception handling technique(s) you choose.

Comment: We're not actually using Magnolia or any of its code. It seems I linked to the wrong part of their page. I was referring to the technique of defining an error event where the error code is the fully-qualified name of an exception class.

Comment: The main disadvantage of the approach described in Magnolia is that you have to have a BPMN Error for every possible exception that can be thrown. However, as you probably saw, jBPM's built in WorkItemHandlers tend to wrap Java Exceptions in a WorkItemHandlerRuntimeException, so if you catch a BPMN2 Error with its classname as error code you are pretty safe for most of jBPM's built in WorkItemHandlers. Are you asking the question only within the context of the built-in handlers or are you looking for advice in handling exceptions in your own WorkItemHandler?

Answer (score 1):

In jBPM 6.2, you can use an `Error` boundary event which you can "attach" to a specific task. So for example, if inside your `Evaluation` task you are throwing a `java.lang.ArithmeticException`, you can use this boundary event to catch the exception and have it go to another task to handle the exception.

Correct me if this is incorrect, but I think the boundary exception handling is asynchrounous with the execution of the task which threw the error.

You can try something like the following:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know you can do this; I've tested the method myself. The point of my question is that I haven't found this method documented in the JBPM documentation. The user guide describes a completely different way for handling exceptions.